# FullCalendar month view, eventRender callback - how to tell which week?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar to display scheduling information for a school.

For some multi-day events, I'd like to prepend the first occurrence of the event in the calendar with a time.  I have this working fine in Day and Week views, using an eventRender callback which simply checks what dates are being rendered, and provided we have the start of the event it prepends the time to the title.

In the month view, an event which spans more than one week causes multiple calls to the eventRender callback.  However, I can find no way of telling which of these callbacks relates to which week.  They all seem to carry the same date information.

Is there any way of telling, within the callback, the date range which that particular element will represent?

Update:

To the request for some sample code - it's a little difficult to produce sample code demonstrating access to some data of which I don't know the whereabouts and which may not exist.  However, I can show the workaround which I've used instead.

In the call to initialize FullCalendar I specify that eventRender events should go to a function called tweakElement, and then the source of that is:

```
tweakElement = (event, element) ->
  if event.prefix
    #
    #  We are being asked, at least some of the time, to put a prefix
    #  on the event's title.  We do this only for elements which show
    #  the chronological start of the event - not those where it
    #  is just continuing.
    #
    if event.start >= @viewStartDate
      if (@viewName == "agendaWeek" ||
          @viewName == "agendaDay" ||
          @viewName == "basicDay")
        element.find('.fc-title').prepend(event.prefix)
      else if @viewName == "month"
        #
        #  This one takes a bit more thought.  The event may occur in
        #  several elements, and only the first gets the prefix.
        #
        if !@elementsSeen[event.id]
          @elementsSeen[event.id] = true
          element.find('.fc-title').prepend(event.prefix)
```

@viewStartDate and @viewName are set at the start of the render, and @elementsSeen is set to be an empty object.  The end result is that the *first* element for the event gets the prefix, and I trust to FullCalendar always passing them in chronological order.

It seems to work, but I worry it's not the nicest way of doing it, nor particularly robust.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Sorry - missed this request.  Gmail filed it automatically.